# Any container cannot connect to MongoDB Replica

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have configured a MongoDB replica set using Docker Compose, and it operates smoothly when accessed outside the Docker environment. However, I encounter an issue with `mongodb-express`, resulting in the error `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017`.

Here's my Docker Compose configuration:

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:7.0.7
    hostname: mongodb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/mongodb/rs-initiate.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/rs-initiate.js
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - default
    command: ["--replSet", "dbrs", "--bind_ip", "0.0.0.0"]
  
  mongodb-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongodb:27017/?replicaSet=dbrs
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    networks:
      - default
```

I've initialized the replica set using `rs-initiate.js`:

```js
rs.initiate();
```

Additionally, when attempting to connect to MongoDB from a Docker container on the same network, I encounter the same issue. Here's an example of the container code:

```py
pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://mongodb:27017/?replicaSet=dbrs")
db = client["users"]
collection = db["messages"]
result = collection.find()

for i in result:
    print(i)
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Could not reach any servers in [('127.0.0.1', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames
or IPs?, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6601e73756219d127e813dcd,
topology_type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27017) server_type: Unknown,
rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('127.0.0.1:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused')>]>
```

Interestingly, the same code executes successfully when run locally on `localhost:27017`.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to resolve this connectivity issue.

Comment: Your service is not listening on `127.0.0.1`. That's the loopback address and it means, "this container". Your mongodb service is running in a service named `mongodb`, so you should use the hostname `mongodb` in order to connect to it.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your question, your `depends_on` configuration doesn't really do anything useful (because the short form of `depends_on` only knows whether or not the named container has started; it doesn't know whether or not the target application is ready to handle requests). If you want to create dependencies between containers, use the [extended form of `depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1).

Comment: @larsks as you can see from the code snippet, I'm using `mongodb:27017` to access MongoDB for queries from the container, and it causes an error. I suspect that something is wrong with the way I set up the mongo db replica, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scripts/rs-initiate.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

initialise() {
    while true
    do
        if mongosh --host mongodb --eval "quit()" &> /dev/null; then
            break
        fi
    done
    mongosh --host mongodb --eval "rs.initiate()"
}

initialise &

mongod --replSet dbrs --bind_ip_all
```

There are probably more elegant ways to do this, but it's a pragmatic solution.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:7.0.7
    container_name: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/rs-initiate.sh:/rs-initiate.sh
    command: ./rs-initiate.sh

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - mongodb
    ports:
        - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
```

[image]

You can test a direct connection to MongoDB from the host using

```
docker run --rm -it --network="host" mongo:7.0.7 mongosh
```

Note that the name of the replica (`dbrs`) appears in the CLI prompt, confirming that you're connected to the right thing!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helped me to fix the connection between the containers. But now I have another problem, I can't connect to MongoDB from the outside using `localhost:27017`, the error I see is: `Could not reach any servers in [('mongodb', 27017)]. Replica set is configured with internal hostnames or IPs?`

Maybe you have some ideas about this?

Comment: Have extended my answer.

Comment: I got it! There are different links to connect. Thanks

Comment: `&directConnection=true` solved issue